# Microsoft Z3 - How to use tactic combinators in the C# API

Tags: z3, smt

I am currently going through following documents:

https://rise4fun.com/z3/tutorial/strategies
http://z3prover.github.io/api/html/namespace_microsoft_1_1_z3.html

In one of our academic research project, we are using Z3 for problem-solving. It is written using Z3 C# API. We want to use the concept of tactics, goals, and sub-goals. We want to give tactics using tactic combinators (aka tacticals). However, in the C# API, I could not find any way to use combinators like (then ..) (or-else ...).

Is there any API function I can use to create such combinators?

The way a single tactic can be used is as follows:

```
Tactic t = Context.MkTactic("simplify");
Context.MkSolver(Tactic)
```

Answer (score 1):

The tactic combinator constructors are on the `Context`, e.g. [`AndThen`](http://z3prover.github.io/api/html/class_microsoft_1_1_z3_1_1_context.html#a6cc503b6c6077975b8f2672b8866c4b0).

Comment: I have one more question. How can I pass parameters when I do checkstat using tactics.

For example:
(check-sat-using
 (par-or
  ;; Strategy 1: using seed 1
  (using-params smt :random-seed 1)
  ;; Strategy 1: using seed 2
  (using-params smt :random-seed 2)
  ;; Strategy 1: using seed 3
  (using-params smt :random-seed 3)))

Comment: The using-params combinator is here: http://z3prover.github.io/api/html/class_microsoft_1_1_z3_1_1_context.html#a3e3d60da381d732b9df8467c0bd9381a